# Failure to create reference razterizer 3D device-

Tags: java-3d

I am using windows 7 and wanted to run "graphing calculator 3D" but when  I execute the file initially, it requires JAVA 3D or DirectX D3D. I have installed both of them to be sure, but the error message has been changed to Failure to create reference razterizer 3D device-DD2DER not available... Is this dangerous to my computer? or what should I do to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you download Graphing Calculator 3D directly from Runiter Company's website?
If so you shouldn't need to install Java3D separately as Java3D is already included with the installer.

I suggest Uninstall any existing Java3D (because they conflict with the included version of Java3D) and then download Graphing Calculator 3D from Runiter website and install it again.

If that didn't work please post the exact error message.